# async await task.run - not found

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, visual-studio-2012, async-await

VS2012, C#, XAML, Windows Phone7 app (just migrated from Win7/VS2010).

I've just migrated my WP7 app to Win8/VS2012. (I mention this in case the issue below might indicate that I may be pointing to an incorrect DLL.)  The app migrated just fine. I'm in the process of adding some additional async processing that I prototyped in VS2012 and am getting flagged by VS that the following  is incorrect:

```
var _Token = await Task.Run(() => (Token)_Serializer.ReadObject(_Response.GetResponseStream()));
```

VS is saying that "System.Threading.Tasks.Task does not contain a definition for 'Run'."  The Reference for System.Threading.Tasks in my WP7 app points to this location:  \packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.0.16-rc\lib\sl4-windowsphone71\System.Threading.Tasks.dll

I added the Microsoft.Bcl.1.0.16-rc via [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) to complete the migration to VS2012. Was this incorrect? Previously I was using AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone and was advised that obtaining Microsoft.Bcl.Async would resolve the build errors such as:

> The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' exists in both AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll' >and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll. 
>   After adding the Microsoft.Bcl.Async the wp7 app built correctly and ran.

It was only after attempting to drop NEW async code I'd prototyped in VS2012 that the Task.Run issue arose.

The app.config contains this entry:

```
<dependentAssembly bcl:name="System.Threading.Tasks">
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.11.0" newVersion="1.5.11.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Is there an additional package I need to install?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: When you prototyped it in VS2012, what platform were you targeting? What NuGet packages did you add?  Microsoft.Bcl isn't going to help - the package needed is Microsoft.Bcl.Async (which depends on Microsoft.Bcl, which might be the point of confusion) - see https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async - also, it requires targeting Windows Phone 7.5 - is that what you're targeting?  I don't think there's an option if you're targeting WP7

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the response. Ido have the Micorsoft.Bcl.Async installed - sorry if I did not make that clear.

Comment: it looks like Task.Run() is a feature of the 4.5 framework. Is it possible to target this framework from WP7? 7.5?  In VS2012, the targets listed in the Project properties are WP7.1 or WP8.0. I attempted to install SDK 7.1.1 and 7.1. These appear to want VS2010 installed as a prerequisite. On Win8, do I need S2010 in order to target Wp7.5 and framework 4.5?

Comment: ah.. I see I may not have answered your initial question: In VS2012 since it was a migrate I targeted WP7.1.  Did not see anyway to opt for the 4.5 framework though.

Comment: wp7.1 is its own target, similar to silverlight. .NET 4.5 is a separate target from windows phone.  They have certain API's in common, especially in the BCL, but they're distinct targets when building. There *is* the target of portable libraries, which can then run on the frameworks you specify it needs to, which might be a potential point of confusion.

Answer (score 16):

In Microsoft.Bcl.Async, just like in the Async CTP, the `Run` method is on the `TaskEx` type instead of `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked, the Async CTP did not work in Visual Studio 2012, as it is an extension of Visual Studio 2010. I am afraid you'll have to stick with VS 2010 as long as you're targeting Windows Phone 7.

Possible more useful information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/03/25/asyncctp-installation-problems-and-vs11.aspx).

Comment: The original Async CTP, yes, but he's using Microsoft.Bcl.Async which works on (and only on) VS2012 and includes targeting WP7.5 and WP8 - see http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the references you still have to the older async CTP assemblies which include the same types (as per compiler error). Those were the right references when using VS2010, but need to be removed now AFAICT.

IMHO, I would do these steps:

- remove the Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Async (via NuGet, however you added them)
- remove the Async CTP libraries (AsyncCtpLibrary*.dll)
- ensure compiling fails to find the types
- add Microsoft.Bcl.Async via NuGet
- ensure compiling works

I don't understand WP7.1 vs 7.5, but since the compiler error mentioned the WP8 ref, I think you're ok.

Answer (score -1):

The Microsoft.Bcl.Async dll from NuGet is fine.

The problem is that the syntax is just different. Don't use:

```
await Task.Run(() => ...);
```

You should just be using:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...);
```