# Let code run for X seconds, after that stop

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, timer, windows-phone

I'm working on Windows Phone 7.1 app and want for several lines of code run for 10 seconds, if succeeds in 10 seconds, continue, if no success, stop the code and display message.
The thing is, my code is not a loop - phone tries to fetch data from a server (if internet connection is slow, might take too long).

```
if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
{
    // start timer here for 10s
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += loginHandler;
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(url + "?loginas=" + login + "&pass=" + pwd)));
    // if 10s passed, stop code above and display MessageBox
}
```

Comment: these can be used for indicating start and end:
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
//code here
(DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds >= 10

but no idea how to stop the code since it isn't a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(10000);

try
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(string.Format(url + 
            "?loginas=" + login + "&pass=" + pwd)), cts.Token);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // work with result
}
catch(TaskCanceledException)
{
    // error/timeout handling
}
```

You need the follwoing NuGet packages:

- [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710)
- [async/await](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

Comment: This need a bit of modification to work on WP7.1 : [async await task.run - not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724051/async-await-task-run-not-found)

Comment: `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Delay'`  
`'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'`  
`The name 'client' does not exist in the current context`  
**If I change client to webClient that I used, then I get this instead:**  
`'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetStringAsync' and no extension method 'GetStringAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: one last question: my old `webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += loginHandler;` should be changed into what? The mothod's arguments: `void loginHandler(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)`

Comment: One way would be to change it to take a string parameter and call it where I put the `work with result` comment.

Comment: 7.1 (for devs) == 7.5 (for users). People would rather say I have WP 7.5 than WP 7.1. It's the exact same OS version

Answer (score 2):

Make that piece of code a method, make that method run separately.
Launch a Timer, when 10 seconds elapsed, check the status of the first thread.
If it has fetched all that he was supposed to, make use of that, otherwise kill the thread, clean whatever you have to clean and return that message of error.

Comment: in that case it will run for 10 seconds no matter what. If it succeeds in fetching data in under 10s, then timer should stop aswell

Comment: In that case, you can set a callback function to be called if the method succeeds before 10 seconds it will return the result and stop the timer.